# Bigcommerce customer login api (single sign-on) invalid login issue

Tags: php, jwt, bigcommerce

I'm new to bigcommerce and jwt tokens.  I'm trying to get the customer login api to work on a trail store.  But have not been able to successfully login a customer automatically.

I got it to work once or twice, but now it doesn't work anymore, and an unable to figure out the odd behavior since nothing changed with the code.  I've tried googling if anyone else has had issues with the customer login api but have found nothing.

I've gone thru the tutorial on https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#customer-login-api and copied the example provided.
Is there something I'm missing with the code below?

- I've gone to developer.bigcommerce.com and created a draft app.
- I got the Client ID and Client Secret from the draft app.
- I've gone into my trial store and successfully installed the draft app.
- I've tested this page on SSL as well.
- Could it be because it's a trail store and it will only work if it's a real store?

Thanks.

Here is the php code below:

```
include "vendor/autoload.php";

use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

function getCustomerLoginToken($id, $redirectUrl = '', $requestIp = '') {
  /*
  if (empty(self::$client_secret)) {
    throw new Exception('Cannot sign customer login tokens without a client secret');
  }
  */

  $payload = array(
     'iss' => '#MyApp1's Client ID#',
     'iat' => time(),
     'jti' => bin2hex(random_bytes(32)),
     'operation' => 'customer_login',
     'store_hash' => '#Store Hash#',
     'customer_id' => $id
  );

  if (!empty($redirectUrl)) {
    $payload['redirect_to'] = $redirectUrl;
  }

  if (!empty($requestIp)) {
    $payload['request_ip'] = $requestIp;
  }

  return JWT::encode($payload, "#MyApp1's Client Secret#", "HS256");
}

$jwt = getCustomerLoginToken(1);

header("Location: " . 'https://store-#Store Hash#.mybigcommerce.com/login/token/' . $jwt);
exit();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of constraints that can cause errors:

- The app must be installed on the store (seems like you're all good here - you can also test with an API token created locally in the store - https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Store-API-Accounts/)
- The app must have the Login OAuth scope
- The JWT URL must be visited within about 30 seconds, or it won't work.
- The computer/server that's generating the JWT needs to have a clock that's synchronized, otherwise your IAT value will appear to have been created more than 30 seconds ago or even in the future which will fail.
- The URL can only be visited exactly once - if anything runs a GET request against it other than the intended end user's browser, it won't work. For example, if you send the URL in a Slack message, slack will try to preview the link by visiting it and therefore invalidate it.
- It's good to double-check that your JWT is valid at https://jwt.io/

BigCommerce support has access to logs which can shed more light on the situation if you've ruled out the above.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

do not need app client_id and Secret code , you need to api's client_id and secret code

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it